# How to make Carousal slider scrolling with 4 images at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a carousal through repeater in asp .net and it works well. but the issue is that it scrolls only one image at a time but i want 4 images together to scroll at a time. I am pasting my code below. I googled it and got some clue that to change "visible:4" in any of the jS files. please help.

```
<div class="well well-small">
                        <h4>Featured Products <small class="pull-right">200+ featured products</small></h4>
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div id="featured" class="carousel slide">
                                <div class="carousel-inner">
                                    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                                        <ItemTemplate>

                                            <div class="item <%# (Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "active" : "") %>">
                                                <ul class="thumbnails">
                                                    <li class="span3">
                                                        <div class="thumbnail" >
                                                            <i class="tag"></i>
                                                            <a href="product_details.html">

                                                                <img src='<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' />
                                                            </a>
                                                            <div class="caption">
                                                                <h5>Product name</h5>
                                                                <h4><a class="btn" href="product_details.html">VIEW</a> <span class="pull-right">$222.00</span></h4>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                </div>
                                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#featured" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
                                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#featured" data-slide="next">›</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: which js library you are using for Carousal

Comment: it is jQuery v1.7.2